# how to relate risk aversion and sharpe ratio in optimisation

Tags: risk, portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, markowitz

I am trying to optimise the following:
U(w)=w′μ−λ/2w′Σw
which is the typical risk aversion problem.
I would like to set lambda in order to have the max sharpe but I cannot find in literature what is the relation between them.
Can anybody help?

Thanks
Luigi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda$ is independent of the maximum sharpe ratio. The maximum sharpe ratio portfolio will give you a combination of the risk free asset and the tangency portfolio. Then your risk aversion just makes you choose the combination between these two assets. See picture below.

[image]

The blue line is the efficient frontier with short-sales allowed. The red-curve is the efficient frontier without short sales. The purple line is the combination between the $r_f$ and the tangency portfolio. Then if your $\lambda$ is high you are investor 1, and tilt more towards risk free. If $\lambda$ is low you are investor 2 and tilt more towards tangency.

Comment: What is the red curve in your plot? Btw I understood what you mean, however if I increase lambda I just start to walk down on the efficient frontier towards the minimum variance..I do not move along the straight line..for lambda equal zero I optimise the max return and lambda tending to infinity it becomes a minimum variance problem..so I do not think that increasing lambda I move on the line..thanks

Comment: When you have a risk-free you are on the straight line of the plot. Not on the efficient frontier. I clarified what the red curve is.

Comment: At the end i made a code which loops through lambda and for each computes the sharpe (actually I never mentioned I have a risk free rate) what I have got is a function like a bell shape, so there exists a relation between them. Then I choose the value of lambda that provided me with an allocation such that the Sharpe was maximum (the top of the bell curve).

Comment: The Sharpe ratio formula has $r_f$ in it. So how can you say "I never mentioned I have a risk free rate"?

Comment: I assume it zero

Comment: Then you still have the purple line starting at zero return and touching the mean-variance efficient frontier at the point where the sharpe ratio is maximized.

Comment: Yes I agree..thanks for your comments

Comment: If you are happy with the answer you should accept it.